# Adicionando e removendo elementos em um array

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```js
var elementos = ["teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4","teste5","teste6","teste7","teste8","teste9","teste10","teste11","teste12"];
var elementosPossui = [];

function carregaTabelas() {
  carregaTabelaElementos();
  carregaTabelaElementosPossui();
  document.getElementById("conteudoArrays").innerHTML = '['+ elementos.toString()+']['+elementosPossui.toString()+']';
};

function carregaTabelaElementos() {
  var k = 0; var tabela = '<table>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tabela += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if(typeof elementos[k] === "undefined"){
        tabela += '<td><span>[0]</span></td>';
        k++;
      }else{
        tabela += '<td><span id="'+elementos[k]+'" onclick="adicionar('+elementos[k]+')">['+elementos[k]+']</span></td>';
        k++;
      }            
    }
    tabela += '</tr>';
  }
  tabela += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("elementos").innerHTML=tabela;
};

function carregaTabelaElementosPossui() {
  var k = 0; var tabela = '<table>';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tabela += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if(typeof elementosPossui[k] === "undefined"){
        tabela += '<td><span>[0]</span></td>';
        k++;
      }else{
        tabela += '<td><span id="'+elementosPossui[k]+'" onclick="remover('+elementosPossui[k]+')">['+elementosPossui[k]+']</span></td>';
        k++;
      }
    }
    tabela += '</tr>';
  }
  tabela += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("elementosPossui").innerHTML=tabela;
};

adicionar = function(id) {
  log = document.getElementById("log");
  var index = elementos.lastIndexOf(id);
  elementosPossui.push(elementos.splice(index, 1));
  carregaTabelas();
  log.innerHTML = index;
};

remover = function(id) {
  log = document.getElementById("log");
  var index = elementosPossui.lastIndexOf(id);
  elementos.push(elementosPossui.splice(index, 1));
  carregaTabelas();
  log.innerHTML = index;
};

carregaTabelas();
```

```html
Selecione um elemento: <div id="elementos"></div>
<br/><br/>
Elementos adicionados: <div id="elementosPossui"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="conteudoArrays"></div>
<br/><br/>
Log: <div id="log"></div>
```

Estou com problema para adicionar e remover do array o elemento que o usuário clicou.

A ideia é que ao selecionar o elemento da primeira tabela, ele seja adicionado na segunda, e ao selecionar um elemento da segunda, ele seja adicionado na primeira, sempre adicionando o elemento no fim da tabela.

Acreditava que a combinação dos métodos `indexOf`, `splice` e `push` desse modo:

```
index = indexOf(valorDoElemento);
array.push(array.splice(index, 1));
```

Solucionariam o problema, ao invés disso ele simplesmente não encontra o elemento no array.

Comment: Por favor, seja mais específico, `Estou com problema para adicionar e remover o elemento do array que o usuário clicou.` não ajuda nem um pouco =)

Comment: Mas no seu exemplo você não esta pegando o elemento clicado, você esta pegando sempre o último.

Comment: Não seria a falta de declaração das variáveis? var adicionar = function... e var remover = function...?

Comment: @gerep eu estava editando a pergunta enquanto você comentou rs
Não necessariamente, estou adicionando o elemento que retornou na posição do index vindo da função indexOf

Comment: Não sei se isso ficou muito claro...

Comment: @IvanFerrer não, não é isso

Comment: Acredito que seu problema está na forma de utilizar o `indexOf`. Está faltando o array =)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio respondi, e no exemplo comentei os códigos que alterei, boa sorte ai nos estudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar tens que alterar os seguintes pontos:

1. **onclick()** - Colocar sua string entre aspas.
2. **splice()** - Retorna um array, no seu caso o elemento sempre estará na posição [0] ao remover e ao adicionar.

Segue o exemplo abaixo com os comentários nas linhas onde foram feita as alterações.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo utilizando socket.io</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_1.9/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>  
    
    <style type="text/css"> h2 { color: #439; font-size: 120%;} </style> 
</head>
<body>    
    Selecione um elemento: <div id="elementos"></div>
    <br/><br/>
    Elementos adicionados: <div id="elementosPossui"></div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="conteudoArrays"></div>
    <br/><br/>
    Log: <div id="log"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elementos = ["teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4","teste5","teste6","teste7","teste8","teste9","teste10","teste11","teste12"];
    var elementosPossui = [];

    function carregaTabelas() {
      carregaTabelaElementos();
      carregaTabelaElementosPossui();
      document.getElementById("conteudoArrays").innerHTML = '['+ elementos.toString()+']['+elementosPossui.toString()+']';
    };

    function carregaTabelaElementos() {
      var k = 0; var tabela = '<table>';
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tabela += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          if(typeof elementos[k] === "undefined"){
            tabela += '<td><span>[0]</span></td>';
            k++;
          }else{
            // NESSA LINHA A FUNCAO PASSA STRING ENTAO COLOCAR ENTRE ASPAS
            tabela += '<td><span id="'+elementos[k]+'" onclick="adicionar(\''+elementos[k]+'\')">['+elementos[k]+']</span></td>';
            k++;
          }            
        }
        tabela += '</tr>';
      }
      tabela += '</table>';
      document.getElementById("elementos").innerHTML=tabela;
    };

    function carregaTabelaElementosPossui() {
      var k = 0; var tabela = '<table>';
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tabela += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          if(typeof elementosPossui[k] === "undefined"){
            tabela += '<td><span>[0]</span></td>';
            k++;
          }else{
            // NESSA LINHA A FUNCAO PASSA STRING ENTAO COLOCAR ENTRE ASPAS
            tabela += '<td><span id="'+elementosPossui[k]+'" onclick="remover(\''+elementosPossui[k]+'\')">['+elementosPossui[k]+']</span></td>';
            k++;
          }
        }
        tabela += '</tr>';
      }
      tabela += '</table>';
      document.getElementById("elementosPossui").innerHTML=tabela;
    };

    adicionar = function(id) {
      log = document.getElementById("log");
      var index = elementos.lastIndexOf(id);
      var arr = elementos.splice(index, 1); // RETORNA UM ARRAY COM 1 ELEMENTO
      elementosPossui.push(arr[0]);
      carregaTabelas();
      log.innerHTML = index;
    };

    remover = function(id) {
      log = document.getElementById("log");
      var index = elementosPossui.lastIndexOf(id);
      var arr = elementosPossui.splice(index, 1); // RETORNA UM ARRAY COM 1 ELEMENTO
      elementos.push(arr[0]);
      carregaTabelas();
      log.innerHTML = index;
    };

    carregaTabelas();
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, mas seria legal já comentar de qualquer forma né. ;) PS: `de qualquer forma = antes do AP apresentar dúvidas`, pra ajudar outros com o mesmo problema e tals...

Comment: rsrs, sim acabei comentando, fica mais didatico, obrigado @gustavox

Comment: Aí sim... :) +1

Comment: @SneepsNinjA era exatamente isso, nunca tinha reparado que o método splice retornava um array de elementos que estão dentro do array

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser, preservar a posição, faça dessa forma, espero que seja o que você precisa:

```html
<html>
<body onload="elementList();">

</body>
<script> 
  var elementos = ["teste1","teste2","teste3","teste4","teste5","teste6","teste7","teste8","teste9","teste10","teste11","teste12"];
   var arrayElementsAdds = [];
function elementList() {

  var tableOne = 'Selecione o elemento:<br><table id="tabela_select"><tr>';

for (var i in elementos) {
  tableOne += (i % 4 == 0) ? '</tr><tr>' : '';
  tableOne += '<td>[<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="addElement('+i+')" id="ele_select_'+i+'">'+elementos[i]+'</span>]</td>';
   }
tableOne +='</tr></table>';

  var tableTwo = 'Elementos adicionados:<br><table id="tabela_select"><tr>';

for (var i in elementos) {
  tableTwo += (i % 4 == 0) ? '</tr><tr>' : '';
  tableTwo += '<td>[<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="backElement('+i+')" id="ele_add_'+i+'">0</span>]</td>';
   }
tableTwo +='</tr></table>';



var html_array = 'var arrayElementsAdd = [';
html_array +='<span id="col"></span>'; 
html_array += ']';

document.write(tableOne+tableTwo+html_array);

}

function removeValueToArray(arr) {

 var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
        arr.splice(ax, 1);
    }
}
return arr;

}

function addElement(pos) {

 var elem1 = document.getElementById('ele_select_'+pos);
 var elem2 = document.getElementById('ele_add_'+pos);
 var col = document.getElementById('col');
  if ( elem1.innerHTML != '0') {
 removeValueToArray(arrayElementsAdds, elem2.innerHTML);
 arrayElementsAdds.push(elem1.innerHTML);
 elem1.innerHTML = elem2.innerHTML;
 elem2.innerHTML = elementos[pos];
 col.innerHTML = arrayElementsAdds;
  }
}

function backElement(pos) {

 var elem1 = document.getElementById('ele_select_'+pos);
 var elem2 = document.getElementById('ele_add_'+pos);
 var col = document.getElementById('col');
if ( elem2.innerHTML != '0') {
  removeValueToArray(arrayElementsAdds, elem2.innerHTML);
  elem1.innerHTML = elem2.innerHTML;
  elem2.innerHTML = '0';
  col.innerHTML = arrayElementsAdds;
}
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Não não @IvanFerrer, pra isso só seria necessário adicionar o elemento no outro array e dar um sort no array rs, mas valeu mesmo assim ^^